# how to automate upload Visual studio gallery through TFS build pipeline

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

how to automate upload Visual studio extension for Visual studio gallery(not marcketplace) through TFS build pipeline. Is there any TFS build task for do this.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is currently no API to do this. You can consider using vsxigallery.com, which supports publishing during build via powershell scripts